# How to align 'search' box to the right side in angular mat table?

Tags: html, css, angular, forms, mat-table

I am using `mat-card` such that `add` button and `search` box need to be aligned horizontally in a single line.
I want `add` to be on left side and `search` to be on the right side.

I have written following `html` but `search` is not aligning to the right side.

```
<div class="page-container">
    <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z3">
        <mat-card-title>Test Data</mat-card-title>
        <form layout-align='center center' layout='column'>
            <mat-form-field style="justify-content: flex-start">
                <button  mat-raised-button (click)="addClick()" color="primary" mat-raised-button>
                    <mat-icon>add_box</mat-icon>Add
                </button>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field style="justify-content: flex-end">
                <input (keyup)="doFilter($event.target.value)" matInput placeholder="Search" type="text">
            </mat-form-field>
        </form>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

I am also getting an error - `ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all, you were trying to use `flexbox`, but there is no `flex` container declared.
- You need to add `display: flex` to the parent element for its child to be `flex` element.
- For aligining your `search` box to the far right, you can use `margin-left: auto`.

```
<div class="page-container">
    <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z3">
        <mat-card-title>Test Data</mat-card-title>
        <form layout-align='center center' layout='column' style="display: flex">
            <mat-form-field>
                <button  mat-raised-button (click)="addClick()" color="primary" mat-raised-button>
          <mat-icon>add_box</mat-icon>Add
        </button>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field style="margin-left: auto">
                <input (keyup)="doFilter($event.target.value)" matInput placeholder="Search" type="text">
      </mat-form-field>
        </form>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

For solving 2nd problem of your question, you can directly follow the official troubleshooting [instruction](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#error-mat-form-field-must-contain-a-matformfieldcontrol):

> **Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl**
>
> This error occurs when you have not added a form field control to your form
> field. If your form field contains a native  or 
> element, make sure you've added the matInput directive to it and have
> imported MatInputModule.